# Can the HTML <cite> Tab Be Used for Periodicals?

Tags: html, citations

I know that <cite> tags are used for "creative" works.

My question is: **Are periodicals such as magazines and newspapers considered "creative works"?**

If not, how does one cite them in HTML?